# How to get the AT5 data from a GGeoXml object

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-mobile

I load an AT5 file into a google map object using the following code:

```
map = new GMap2(document.getElementById("map_canvas"));
geoXml = new GGeoXml(at5);
GEvent.addListener(geoXml, "load", function() {
    geoXml.gotoDefaultViewport(map);
    // I would like to read the AT5 contents here
});
map.addOverlay(geoXml);
```

Thanks for any kind of help.

Answer (score 0):

This does not refer to Version 3 of the Maps API. GMap2, GGeoXml and GEvent are all part of Version 2.

GGeoXml is opaque: you cannot inspect it. Use a third-party parser if you want the content to be available.

There's a rather old list available at http://econym.org.uk/gmap/extensions.htm -- have a look at EGeoXml and GeoXml.